# combining elements of a list 3 at the time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm struggling to understand how to combine elements from a list.

I have:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

I want to create triplets by taking elements from each list members
but always including the first element. This piece of code does half the
job:

```
r=[[]]
for x in a[0:3]:
    t = []
    for y in x:
        for i in r:
            t.append(i+[y])
r = t
```

r

```
[[1, 3, 6], [2, 3, 6], [1, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [1, 5, 6], [2, 5, 6]]
```

but I also want:

```
[[1,6,7], [1,6,8], [1,6,9] etc.]
```

Could someone please suggest a good method to do that?

Comment: It would be useful if you give the full desired **output**.

Comment: What principe you mean at `[[1,6,7], [1,6,8], [1,6,9] etc.]`?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools

a = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
for xss in itertools.combinations(a, 3): # pick 3 lists.
    # xss => ([1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6])
    #        ([1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10])
    #        ...

    indexed = [enumerate(x) for x in xss]
    # indexed => [[(0, 1), (1, 2)], [(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5)], [(0, 6)]]
    #             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ list(enumerate([1, 2]))

    for xs in itertools.product(*indexed):
        # xs => ((0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 6))
        #       ((0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 7))
        #       ((0, 1), (0, 6), (0, 7))
        #        ...
        if all(i > 0 for i, x in xs): # exclude no first item is selected.
            continue
        print [x for i, x in xs]
```

---

**UPDATE** response to the comment.

```
import itertools

a = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
for xss in itertools.combinations(a[1:], 2):
    xss = (a[0],) + xss
    indexed = [enumerate(x) for x in xss]
    for xs in itertools.product(*indexed):
        if all(i > 0 for i, x in xs):
            continue
        print [x for i, x in xs]
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 6]
[1, 4, 6]
[1, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 6]
[2, 4, 6]
[2, 5, 6]
[1, 3, 7]
[1, 3, 8]
[1, 3, 9]
[1, 3, 10]
[1, 4, 7]
[1, 4, 8]
[1, 4, 9]
[1, 4, 10]
[1, 5, 7]
[1, 5, 8]
[1, 5, 9]
[1, 5, 10]
[2, 3, 7]
[2, 3, 8]
[2, 3, 9]
[2, 3, 10]
[2, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 7]
[1, 6, 7]
[1, 6, 8]
[1, 6, 9]
[1, 6, 10]
[2, 6, 7]
[2, 6, 8]
[2, 6, 9]
[2, 6, 10]
```

Comment: Thank you 'falsetru' it is an elegant way of solving the problem but note that the last 12 entries shouldn't be there, they don't include an element of the 1st list. It shouldn't be difficult to modify your code to do that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Augusto, Why don't' you update your question with expected output?

Comment: The output should be this:[1, 3, 6]
[1, 4, 6]
[1, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 6]
[2, 4, 6]
[2, 5, 6]
[1, 3, 7]
[1, 3, 8]
[1, 3, 9]
[1, 3, 10]
[1, 4, 7]
[1, 4, 8]
[1, 4, 9]
[1, 4, 10]
[1, 5, 7]
[1, 5, 8]
[1, 5, 9]
[1, 5, 10]
[2, 3, 7]
[2, 3, 8]
[2, 3, 9]
[2, 3, 10]
[2, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 7]
[1, 6, 7]
[1, 6, 8]
[1, 6, 9]
[1, 6, 10]
[2, 6, 7]
[2, 6, 8]
[2, 6, 9]
[2, 6, 10]